# How to put links on a TextView?

Tags: android, listview

I want to put links on a TextView, i've put `android:autoLink="web"`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/text_prix"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

and when i tap on the link i have the browser that it is opened correctly. But i want to dispaly on the textview a TAG for every link. How can i make this ?
Example:
For the link www.google.fr I want to jsut show on the ListView "Google".
Is that possible?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Linkify ! 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Or you can add Onclick action to your textview
Example :

```
Textview text;
text = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: onClick ? How to open a browser with a predefined URL ?